# Save datagridview to separate excel or PDF files based on content

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I currently have my datagridview importing data from a mysql table. Once the information is imported (usually 1000 rows by 15 columns), the user has the ability to export the data to excel. The user must then run a macro to separate the data into separate sheets by on the contents in column 1 (group the same rows together based on the value), then run another macro to save each individual sheet to it's own email file in a folder. The contents of column 1 can have the save values - for example

[image]

Is there any possibility of having vb.net automatically perform this function in the following steps once the user clicks a button:

1. Sort the dgv by the contents in column 1,
2. start saving the data based on the content in column 1 into separate files in a designated folder (all the jim's and bill's would be in a particular folder)
3. the file name would be the name of the content in column 1.
4. have a pop up once it's complete indicating there the items are saved.

Current code I am using for dgv to excel export.

```
  'export to excel
    'verfying the datagridview having data or not
    If ((DataGridView1.Columns.Count = 0) Or (DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0)) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Creating dataset to export
    Dim dset As New DataSet
    'add table to dataset
    dset.Tables.Add()
    'add column to that table
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        dset.Tables(0).Columns.Add(DataGridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText)
    Next
    'add rows to the table
    Dim dr1 As DataRow
    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        dr1 = dset.Tables(0).NewRow
        For j As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1
            dr1(j) = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value
        Next
        dset.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dr1)
    Next

    Dim excel As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wBook As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim wSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet

    wBook = excel.Workbooks.Add()
    wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet()

    Dim dt As System.Data.DataTable = dset.Tables(0)
    Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
    Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
    Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
    Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0

    For Each dc In dt.Columns
        colIndex = colIndex + 1
        excel.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
    Next

    For Each dr In dt.Rows
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        colIndex = 0
        For Each dc In dt.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            excel.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)

        Next
    Next

    wSheet.Columns.AutoFit()
    Dim strFileName As String = "C:\exports\jim.xls"
    Dim blnFileOpen As Boolean = False
    Try
        Dim fileTemp As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(strFileName)
        fileTemp.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        blnFileOpen = False
    End Try

    If System.IO.File.Exists(strFileName) Then
        System.IO.File.Delete(strFileName)
    End If

    wBook.SaveAs(strFileName)
    excel.Workbooks.Open(strFileName)
    excel.Visible = True
```